# getting connection state for GRPC

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

I am trying to get the connection state for a GRPC (Java API) connection via the call copied below.  Based on the notes I could find online, it seemed as if GRPC client would lazily connect to the server on the first service call & if I wanted to establish the connection before the service call, I could use this option.  However, this call seems to always prevent my application from connecting to the server and I was wondering if I had to rely on a different call/mechanism.

GRPC version: 1.1.2
JDK version:1.8

```
final ManagedChannelBuilder<?> channelBuilder = connection.getSecure();  //this forms a secure connection
channel = channelBuilder.build();
ConnectivityState connectivityState = channel.getState(true); //referenced in question above
asyncStub = MonetaGoConnectGrpc.newStub(channel);
```

Comment: Instead of just saying "does not work", also provide the actual failure exception or behavior.

Comment: the comment was there to indicate the line inside the code snippet which I was pointing to in the question above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: `getState(true)` was implemented in [grpc-java v1.6.1](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/releases/tag/v1.6.1) (Aug 31, 2017), although it was incomplete. It was later completed in [grpc-java v1.11.0](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/releases/tag/v1.11.0) (Mar 30, 2018).

Original answer:

It [isn't currently implemented](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/2292) for most `ManagedChannel`s. The API was introduced for the new `LoadBalancer` API, but now not even `LoadBalancer` is using it.

I've filed [an issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/2883) to improve the documentation until it is implemented.

Your understanding of the Channel's behavior is correct. It lazily connects and this is the API that can force-connect the Channel. Unfortunately, it isn't yet implemented and there's not an alternative other than issuing an RPC.

Comment: thanks for following up.  It would be ideal to be able to query the connection state before the first RPC or some other clean way to figure out why the first RPC did not work (whether the issue was with the RPC or with getting the connection established)

Comment: The RPC's Status includes failure information, independent of the source of failure. So if the connection couldn't be established, the Status should describe in what way it failed.

Comment: They have a method for this, although it might not be implemented for all client variants, it should be for the core ones now: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/v1.20.0/core/src/main/java/io/grpc/ManagedChannel.java#L84 and https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/connectivity-semantics-and-api.md