# GRPC ConnectivityState is not working true?

Tags: java, state, grpc, channel, connectivity

```
ManagedChannel managedChannel = ManagedChannelBuilder
                    .forAddress("localhost", 9090)
                    .usePlaintext().build();

System.out.println("State: " + managedChannel .getState(false)) // State: IDLE

Grpc.Stub stub = Grpc.newStub(managedChannel);

System.out.println("State: " + managedChannel .getState(false)) // State: IDLE

stub.callMethod();

System.out.println("State: " + managedChannel .getState(false)) // State: IDLE
```

Above code is GRPC client. It get connection with grpc server. But every time the channel state is IDLE? When is CONNECTING and READY state? Whats wrong?

Comment: I think you should refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43284217/getting-connection-state-for-grpc

Comment: its not useful for me

Comment: What version of gRPC Java are you using?

Comment: 1.30 version  grpc

Answer (score 2):

It is required to wait for another state.
The following code prints `connection state: TRANSIENT_FAILURE` when server is not started and `connection state: READY` when it is healthy.
gRPC version: 1.24.0

```
ManagedChannel managedChannel = ManagedChannelBuilder
    .forAddress("localhost", 9090)
    .usePlaintext().build();
 
ConnectivityState state = channel.getState(true);
while (state == ConnectivityState.IDLE || state == ConnectivityState.CONNECTING) {
    state = channel.getState(true);
}

System.out.println("connection state: " + state.toString());
```